# Swing - Incluir imagens no arquivo JAR

Tags: java, swing, jar, image

Tenho um projeto em JAVA, que possui uma interface gráfica com uma tela, desenvolvida com o **Swing**.

Tenho 2 imagens, background e favicon, que estão no pacote: 
[code]br\com\drsolutions\monitorar\imagens[/code]

Estrutura do Projeto:
br\com\drsolutions\monitorar\imagens
    Fundo.jpg
    icone.png
br\com\drsolutions\monitorar\rede
    TestarIcmp.java
br\com\drsolutions\monitorar\ux
    InterfaceGrafica.java
br\com\drsolutions\monitorar
    Aplicativo.java

No arquivo **InterfaceGrafica.java**, adiciono as imagens no JFrame da seguinte forma:

```
...
jFrame = new JFrame("Monitorar");
jFrame.setSize(246, 410);
jFrame.setResizable(false);
jFrame.setLayout(null);
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

/* Colocar a imagem no background e o ícone na janela */
try {
    jFrame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
            ImageIO.read(new File("src\\br\\com\\drsolutions\\monitorar\\imagens\\Fundo.jpg")))
    ));
    jFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("src\\br\\com\\drsolutions\\monitorar\\imagens\\icone.png")
            .getImage()
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    return false;
}
...
```

Como posso adicionar as imagens sem precisar passar o caminho completo dessa forma?

Como fazer com que as imagens funcionem no arquivo JAR que eu gero?

Obrigado,
Diego M. Rodrigues

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma pasta dentro de *src/main* com o nome de **resources**, depois mova a pasta *imagens* para dentro de *resources* e mude o path para:

```
new File(getClass().getResources("imagens/Fundo.jpg"));
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResources("imagens/icone.jpg")).getImage();
```